# ViewPager (nested in a Fragment) using FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

[CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) has [awesome examples](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager) on the use of `ViewPager`s.

I am particularly interested in the [Nested](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested) example where the `ViewPager` is inside a fragment. The thing is, the adapter implementation uses the `FragmentPagerAdapter` and not the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Is there any particular reason?

How can I conserve the states of my pages *inside* the `ViewPager` *inside* my fragment?

Answer (score 1):

> CommonsWare has awesome examples on the use of ViewPagers.

Ummm... thanks!

> Is there any particular reason?

There are only a few fragments. The benefits of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` come when you have lots of potential pages, where the heap usage of having lots of those in memory simultaneously would be expensive. For example, maybe you have an ebook reader using a `ViewPager` with a `WebView` per chapter. For [a 3,000+ page book spread over nearly 200 chapters](https://commonsware.com/Android), having ~200 `WebView` widgets would be rather expensive if the user swipes through lots of them, and so a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` makes sense.

> How can I conserve the states of my pages inside the ViewPager inside my fragment?

Outside of this one book sample, I avoid nested fragments like the plague. However, I am not aware of any particular problems with using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in a `ViewPager`-inside-a-`Fragment` scenario. However, please bear in mind that `FragmentPagerAdapter` just keeps the fragments around — it's not like their state is somehow being dropped.

Comment: ah. it s resetting the values in the page fragments because I m reinitializing the controls 'onCreateView' .. I should use smth else maybe.